# rails activerecord reputation system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to use the rails activerecord reputation system from twitter and I'm running into an error while trying to generate a reputation system:

```
/Users/chrispalmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-
4.1.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method
`attr_accessible' for #<Class:0x0000010190f838> (NoMethodError)
```

I looked around and it might have something to do with "strong params"?  If so, how can I fix this problem.  I tried installing protected-attributes gem, but it did not fix the issue.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Rails 4 uses Strong Parameters to control (permit/require/reject) attributes for a specific Model when editing/creating. You can find a lot of Guide about it, just ask Google ;)

Comment: I understand how to use strong params, but does that mean I have to go back and change all of my controllers just to install this gem?

Comment: Actually, you can just add this to your gemfile: 

gem 'activerecord-reputation-system', github: 'NARKOZ/activerecord-reputation-system', branch: 'rails4'

This solved the issue.  Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in `activerecord-reputation-system` which was fixed in 3.0.1 (November 27, 2014). Please update.